# Is there a way to override the Unix terminal find command?

Tags: unix, terminal, find, command

Eg:  Find command to search for txt files

```
find . -iname "*.txt"
```

I want to create an alias of `find` command in `.bash_profile` so that upon sourcing `.bash_profile` I should be able to pass any arguments to find command to search the file types:

```
find txt find pdf find doc
```

I tried below syntax to override find command as:

```
find ./ -iname "$1"
```

where $1 can be any argument file type.

Comment: I would recommend using a new name.  Aliases don't handle positional arguments well; use a function.  Your notation `find txt find pdf find doc` is odd; was that meant to be 3 separate commands or 1 compound command?  (Before editing, they were all on one line, so I left them on one line, but it seems more likely that you intended 3 separate commands.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a bash script?

```
#!/bin/sh

for var in "$@"; do
    find . -iname "*.$var"
done
```

You can store this in a file, make it executable (`chmod +x find-by-type`), then copy it to a directory within your PATH variable. Executing would be as easy as calling:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ find-by-type pdf txt doc
```

Comment: I prefer standalone scripts to either aliases (in particular) or functions.  There are occasions for the alternatives, but speed isn't going to be an issue with a `find` command, and the cleanliness of a separate script is a good idea.

Comment: You might think about using this: `command=( find . -iname "*.$1" );
shift;
for opt in "$@"; do command+=( -o -iname "*.$opt" ); done;
"${command[@]}"` which builds up a single `find` command to run all the searches in a single execution of `find`.  That is more economical (especially on big trees) than running multiple `find` commands.  You could prefix the final command with `exec` for a marginal (non-measurable) gain.  The downside is that the file types would be interleaved in the output, rather than segregated by file suffix.

Comment: Good idea, @JonathanLeffler. In addition, you'd also get the files back ordered by folder/name instead of by type/folder/name.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `.bashrc` file (it is usually hidden press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see) in your home directory and append this line.

```
alias finder="find . -type f -regex "
```

Note I use `-regex` which will help you match your file extension patterns.

Then execute in a shell:

```
source .bashrc
```

Afterwards, call your alias named `finder` with your filename/extension.

For example:

```
finder '*\(txt\|py\|pdf\|lst\)'
```

Comment: One thing to be careful about: This would match the file named "CntxtSnstv.png". You'd need to call it without the second asterisk at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I tried something like writing a function in `.bash_profile`:

```
findFile(){
    find $1 -iname "*.$2"
}
```

sourced `.bash_profile`

```
export -f findFile

findFile ~/Desktop txt
```

Comment: Note that you should probably wrap `$1` in double quotes too if you ever have directory names that contain spaces (etc).